# Push notification for windows phone 8 for getting URI

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mpns

I have developed Windows Phone 8 application and I have implemented Push Notification Service in it.
When I start Application in windows Phone Emulator it creates URI(Getting from MPNS) and send it to the Database for sending notification next time, But the **Problem is that when I restart my Emulator the URI get changed**, I want to keep the same URI for the Device or Emulator so how can I do that?

My code for generating the URI is

```
HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;
        string channelName = "TileSampleChannel";
        InitializeComponent();
        pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);
        if (pushChannel == null)
        {
            pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
            pushChannel.Open();
            pushChannel.BindToShellTile();
        }
        else
        {
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
           // MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}", pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));
            string strURI = pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString();
            (App.Current as App).phoneURI = strURI;
        }
```

I Picked this **(App.Current as App).phoneURI** and Sent to Database but it get change when I restart emulator?

And sometime it gives URI and sometime it throws an exception **An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in TileNotificationClient.DLL but was not handled in user code** on this line `string strURI = pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString();`

Comment: Regarding your NullReferenceException: Can you check that your channel actucally has a channelUri? Not sure, but if it wasn't opened completely, sometimes it does not have a channel uri yet.

Answer (score 0):

The (imho) good side of the emulator is, that you have a fresh, clean system every time you restart it.

The Notifikation uri is not guarantied to be consistent on real devices either. You should incorporate changing channel Uris in your application design.